# Abilities that need a name and unnamed tokens

Tags: magic-the-gathering

I am fairly sure on this one, but I wanted to ask to be really sure.

Say I have [Secrets of Paradise](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=382356) and a deck with a lot of [Rousing of Souls](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=382348).

Am I right in thinking that because the tokens made by *Rousing of Souls* are just "1/1/ white Spirit" tokens (no name), there is no way for them to gain the tapping for mana ability that *Secrets of Paradise* can grant?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Actually, the tokens made by Rousing of Souls will have the name "Spirit" by 110.5c:

> 110.5c. A spell or ability that creates a creature token sets both its name and its creature type. If the spell or ability doesn't specify the name of the creature token, its name is the same as its creature type(s). A "Goblin Scout creature token," for example, is named "Goblin Scout" and has the creature subtypes Goblin and Scout. Once a token is on the battlefield, changing its name doesn't change its creature type, and vice versa.

However, as there is no *card* named "Spirit", you cannot name it for Secrets of Paradise (per 201.3).

> 201.3. If an effect instructs a player to name a card, the player must choose the name of a card that exists in the Oracle card reference (see rule 108.1) and is legal in the format of the game the player is playing. (See rule 100.6.) If the player wants to name a split card, the player must choose the name of one of its halves, but not both. (See rule 708.) If the player wants to name a flip card's alternative name, the player may do so. (See rule 709.) If the player wants to name the back face of a double-faced card, the player may do so. (See rule 711.) A player may not choose the name of a token unless it's also the name of a card.

Note that situations have occurred in the past, where "token names" have later been elevated to "card name" status. For example, in Future Sight, the white spellshaper, Goldmeadow Lookout made tokens named "Goldmeadow Harrier". At the time, you could not name "Goldmeadow Harrier" if an effect asked you to name a card. Sometime later, in Lorwyn block, Goldmeadow Harrier was actually printed [as a creature card](http://magiccards.info/query?q=!Goldmeadow+Harrier), which then *did* allow you name it if an effect asked you to name a card.

Comment: This is a very interesting / weird thing about MTG rules... these particular 2 cards can't work together, but if in the next set they created a card named "Spirit", suddenly this combo could work; even though it doesn't make much sense that it should have that effect.

Comment: @GendoIkari True, though I suspect that they regard basic token names as "taken" (in addition to being not really good interesting names) and will avoid doing that.

Comment: @Gendolkari: It actually did occur previously with Goldmeadow Lookout making tokens named "Goldmeadow Harrier"... which didn't show up as a card until a few blocks later!

Comment: @HaoYe Can you edit that into your answer?

Comment: @GendoIkari I agree that this is a dumb rule. The name of a printed card should have no effect on its functionality, or the functionality of other cards around it (maybe in an unset). Just let us name any name that we want.

Comment: @Cruncher I'm a big fan of Dominion, where the rules make it clear that you can choose to name "Ace of Diamonds" if you need to name a card.

Comment: @GendoIkari Actually, they couldn't generally (although Lore Seeker specifically in conspiracy could make this complicated) according to 

**201.3**: "If an effect instructs a player to name a card, the player must choose the name of a card that 
exists in the Oracle card reference (see rule 108.1) and is legal in the format of the game the player 
is playing." I'm not sure of the ruling on whether Lore Seeker makes all cards ever printed in any set with boosters legal, or whether it only makes sets that were actually chosen legal.

Comment: @JakeP There are several formats for which a new card named "Spirit" would be legal in the same format as an existing card that has you name a card.